# Appengine gcloud deploy using custom service account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to deploy an API to app engine But it ends up using the wrong service account.
I use these 3 cmd lines in gitlab:

```
 - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
 - gcloud config set account NameOfServiceAccount.com
 - gcloud app deploy
```

What I get is

```
target service account:      [App Engine default service account]
Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Beginning deployment of service [lettering-back]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 2 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED: You do not have permission to act as
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To deploy new versions, a member must have the Service Account User
> (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) role on the App Engine default service
> account, and the Cloud Build Editor (roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor)
> and Cloud Storage Object Admin (roles/storage.objectAdmin) roles on
> the project.

More specifically for your error message you gonna need `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` on your service account whose key is the one you placed at `/tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json`

Reference : the first table row at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/roles#predefined_roles